# How to undelete my deleted question?

Tags: support, questions, undelete

Yesterday I created a question. But because I thought that I won't get far with the Answers, I deleted it.

Now I've found a rather good solution by myself and I would like to post it as an answer so others can see it since there doesn't exist a clean solution for this problem in my eyes.

How do I undelete my deleted question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions)

The default tab is Summary tab.

Click on the title Questions (x)

in the bottom, you can see Deleted recent questions. Click on it.

Or use direct link

```
https://site.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<userid>
```

Click on the title of the question you want to undelete

In the bottom of the question, you will see an *undelete* link (along with Edit and other links). Click on that and it will undelete the question

Comment: Yes I know, but I've already closed this view...

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: the link did it for me. Thanks a lot